# What is this locking pin for a hinge called?

Tags: safety, hinge

The following is a picture of a locking pin for a tubular hinge which specifies Maritime use. I assume it has something to do with railings but I'm thinking of fabricating my own similar hinges. "Locking pin" seems awfully vague. I know I've seen this before; the little nub at the end is spring loaded and presses into the pin

[image]

Comment: Go to an agricultural machinery supplier - they have many...

Comment: a retaining pin, generally. "ring pin", or "ring pin with detent" should get good search results

Comment: This is also sometimes colloquially called a cotter pin, hitch pin, clevis pin or even pivot pin. But I kind of doubt you'll find it on a parts list under those names.

Comment: A cotter pin is made from bent wire, that's pretty distinct IMO

Comment: The answer by @jko got it specifically -- one other name commonly used for this and similar shapes is a "pip pin"

Answer (score 13):

That is a ring-grip quick-release pin, sometimes referred to as clevis pins. [McMaster link](https://www.mcmaster.com/retaining-pins/end-type%7Espring-loaded-ball/head-type%7Ering/)

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for. Even  a Google reverse photo search didn't find an answer.

Comment: McMaster >>> Google